# Are there any disadvantages of `cp --sparse=always`?

Tags: cp, coreutils, sparse-files

Is there any reason **not** to use use `--sparse=always` with every invocation to `cp`?

`info cp` says:

> ```
> ‘--sparse=WHEN’
>      A “sparse file” contains “holes”—a sequence of zero bytes that does
>      not occupy any physical disk blocks; the ‘read’ system call reads
>      these as zeros.  This can both save considerable disk space and
>      increase speed, since many binary files contain lots of consecutive
>      zero bytes.  By default, ‘cp’ detects holes in input source files
>      via a crude heuristic and makes the corresponding output file
>      sparse as well.  Only regular files may be sparse.
>
>     The WHEN value can be one of the following:
> ```

...

> ```
>     ‘always’
>           For each sufficiently long sequence of zero bytes in the input
>           file, attempt to create a corresponding hole in the output
>           file, even if the input file does not appear to be sparse.
>           This is useful when the input file resides on a file system
>           that does not support sparse files (for example, ‘efs’ file
>           systems in SGI IRIX 5.3 and earlier), but the output file is
>           on a type of file system that does support them.  Holes may be
>           created only in regular files, so if the destination file is
>           of some other type, ‘cp’ does not even try to make it sparse.
> ```

It also says:

> [...] with the following alias, ‘cp’ will use the minimum amount of space supported by the file system.
>
> ```
> alias cp='cp --reflink=auto --sparse=always'
> ```

Why isn't `--sparse=always` the default?

Comment: It’s incompatible with `--reflink`, apart from that I don’t know...

Comment: perhaps just because the developers wanted to utilise the principle of least surprise, or because POSIX specified otherwise? (is cp even in posix, i forget)

Comment: Checking for sparseness might be detrimal to performance, sparse files may cause severe filesystem fragmentation, and there was at least one instance of data corruption with `cp --sparse`.

Comment: @frostschutz the default still creates sparse files, with `always` the behaviour is slightly different. If you want to avoid the issues you mention, you need to disable sparse writes with `--sparse=never` explicitly.

Comment: To clarify, as I understand it the default copies existing holes, `always` also looks for runs of zeroes which could be used to create new holes.

Comment: Copying the data for (mainly non-sparse) files through a read/write loop involves dma of data into and out of memory, whereas looking for runs of zeroes implied by *always* (or *auto* where the number of blocks doesn't match the file size) will drag the data into the cpu caches and involve much more cpu bandwidth and cycles.

Comment: Similar: [Why is cp --reflink=auto not the default behaviour?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/80351)

Comment: @cat `cp` is in POSIX, but GNU `cp` implements extra stuff.

Comment: @StephenKitt It *is* compatible with --reflink: `info cp` contains: `with the following alias, ‘cp’ will use the minimum amount of space
     supported by the file system.`  `alias cp='cp --reflink=auto --sparse=always'`

Comment: @Tom hah, serves me right for just [reading the source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cp.c#n1157) and not seeing the `auto` variant!

Comment: I like the way you roll, @StephenKitt!

Comment: Some bootloaders don't like holes in files...

Comment: lseek (which is needed for that to work) may not work [properly] on some filesystems/drivers. Like over NFS before version 4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385803/fseek-performance-drop-over-nfs Or various bugs: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2020-10/msg00014.html

Answer (score 3):

There are a few reasons why it is not default, one is backwards compatibility, performance, and last but not least, the principle of least surprise.

My understanding is that when you enable this option, there is CPU overhead which might not necessarily be acceptable, besides, backwards compatibility is also key. The `cp` command works reliably without, it does add a little space saving, but these days, that really is negligible, in most cases at least ...

I think the comments you received also highlighted other reasons.

Principle of least surprise means you do not change something needlessly, `cp` has been around for decades, changing its default behavior will upset many veterans.

Comment: How big is the CPU overhead of `--sparse`?